# NODEJS and mysql-node and no databases changes

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

My code:

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : '192.168.2.20',
  user     : 'test',
  password : '123123123',
  database : 'dbtest',
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
  // connected! (unless `err` is set)
});

var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO posts (title) VALUES("data1");');
```

Everytime I run this `SELECT * FROM dbtest.posts;` using MySQL Workbench I never see any changes or results.

What am I doing wrong that NodeJS using mysql-node is not correctly editing my DB?

EDIT:

```
admin$ node debug test.js
< debugger listening on port 5858
connecting... ok
break in test.js:1
  1 var mysql      = require('mysql');
  2 var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  3   host     : '192.168.2.20',
debug>
```

Do I have a problem in calling my files? They are kept under node_modules and the file is in the same root directory as node_modules

Comment: Do you get an error from the Node.js code?  Note that you need to pass a callback.

Comment: Pass a callback? I do not seem to get any errors when I run node test.js from console.

Comment: What happens if you try your query inside the `connect` callback?

Comment: Yes, I still have the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not being able to insert data with the code in your example probably because your MySQL server is with the `autocommit` system variable set to `false`.

What you can do in this case is to set this variable to `true` (see de [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_autocommit)) or change your code to force the commit, like:

```
connection.query('INSERT INTO posts (title) VALUES("data1");', function(err, result) {
  if (err) { 
    connection.rollback(function () {
      throw err;
    });
  }
  connection.commit(function (err) {
    if (err) { 
      connection.rollback(function () {
        throw err;
      });
    }
    console.log('Commited!');
  });
});
```

Comment: @Frank Was this answer helpful? Have you solved your problem?